# Displaying array of a class in tableView cell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class

I declared a class with all the variables in it.

```
class Xyz
{
  var a: String?
  var b: String?
}
```

In other viewController, I am declaring an array of that class.

```
 var arr = [Xyz]()
 var arr2 = ["title1","title2"]
```

After Json Parsing, I am appending the values in this array.

```
var temp = Xyz()
var dict = item as! NSDictionary
temp.a = (dict.value(forKey: "a") as? String) ?? ""
temp.b = (dict.value(forKey: "b") as? String) ?? ""
self.arr.append(temp)
```

**How should I display this array in a cell?**

```
cell.textLabel?.text = arr2[indexPath.row]
//The above array shows the title of the row
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(describing: arr[indexPath.row])
//indexPath doesn't work here (error: indexPath out of range)
//The reason is the 'arr' array has class in it
```

The above statement gives error as the array has class in it and not the values.

```
 cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(describing: arr[0].a)
 cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(describing: arr[0].b)
```

is the only way I can access my values.
Due to which I am unable to display this array in my tableView.

How to display the content of the array on a tableView cell(each on separate cell)?

Comment: What property do you want to show in your cell an `a` or `b`

Comment: I have a table with title and subtitle. And two arrays. One predefined and other getting from Json parsing. I need to display the array that I am getting from json parsin with respect to the array predefined

Comment: `title1` will be the title and value of `a` got from json parsing will be the subtitle of that row.

Comment: `self.arr.append(value)` what is `value` in there? did you mean `temp`?

Comment: So why don't you use `String(describing: arr[indexPath.row].a)`?

Comment: @nayem indexPath won't work here. Reason:- the `arr` contains [0] and in that indexPath of [0] contains key-value pair obtained by json parsing.

Comment: You are assigning `temp.a = (dict.value(forKey: "a") as? String) ?? ""` and saying array indices contain `Key:Value` pair. Are you serious? 

Comment: @nayem yes I am serious and I think you didn't understood what's the question yet, `temp.a = (dict.value(forKey: "a") as? String) ?? ""` is parsed from json. `temp.a` is the variable declared in the `class Xyz` and `(dict.value(forKey: "a") as? String) ?? ""` is the value obtained by json parsing for key a. The reason I have kept the variable name and key name is to understand that the naming are same. Good going for that down vote.

Comment: No. I clearly understood your issue. You yourself are saying ___...is the value obtained by json parsing for key a___. So where does the `indexPath.row` contain `Key:Value` pair at all?

Comment: @nayem `arr[0]` contains the key-value pairs. so arr[indexpath.row] won't work. Instead of that `arr[0].a` and `arr[0].b` will be needed to access the values. indexPath is workable only for the second array where `arr2 = [String]`.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, you are designing the workflow in the wrong direction. Do you think everyone who posted answers and comments isn't understanding your need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through all the below answers. But none of them produced the solution. The problem in all solution is the `array` is printed on same cell, leaving the other cell empty(including the answer provided by Vadian - it will give error because it is printing all the value in same row.). While printing an `array` on a cell, you have to go in a loop, But none of the answers provides that. This will give error back `Index out of range` .The best solution I came across is to use `switch` or `enum`. Due to `switch` or `enum` you can put a condition for every row and according to that you can print the item from the `array`. Here I put the simple `array` item "title" as `case` and according to that printed the `array` of class.

**Solution**:- The following code helped me to achieve what I asked.

Note:- `enum` is more preferred than `switch`. I used `switch` because easy to understand and got my work done.

```
let a = arr2[indexPath.row]
let item = arr[0]

switch a
{
case "title1":
   cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.a
   return cell
case "title2" :
   cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.b
   return cell
default:
   break
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many mistakes / bad programming habits in the code.

First of all name the class starting with a capital letter and declare the properties non-optional because they are going to contain non-optional values. (Declaring optionals as an alibi not to write an initializer is one of the bad habits.)

Include the *title of the row* from `arr2` as `title` property in the class, that avoids any *out of range* exception.

```
class Xyz
{
    var a : String
    var b : String
    var title : String

    init(a: String, b: String, title: String) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

Declare the data source array

```
var arr = [Xyz]() // `var arr: [xyz]()` does not compile
```

Populate the data source array

```
let dict = item as! [String:Any] // Swift Dictionary !!
let temp = Xyz(a: dict["a"] as? String) ?? "", b: dict["b"] as? String) ?? "", title: "title1")
self.arr.append(temp) // `self.arr.append(value)` does not compile
```

In `cellForRow` get the `Xyz` instance from the array and use the properties

```
let item = arr[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = item.title

cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.a + " " + item.b
```

Since all properties are strings anyway, all `String(describing` initializers (create `String` from `String`) are nonsensical.

Comment: Corrected my mistakes in question. `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.a + " " + item.b` will print the value of a and b on same line. I need them on different line for each row. so `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.a` on first line and `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.b in other row

Comment: Then your design is wrong. `cellForRow` is called for each row separately. Each item in the data source array represents **one** row.

Comment: Sir, after Json parsing, the first array `arr` contains the class Xyz with key-value pairs. So `arr[0].a=value` , ` arr[0].b=value` . So my question is I want that `arr` to display its each value on each row. There is nothing wrong in designing. I can feel its achievable. Just need a good logic to achieve what I want.

Comment: This answer getting upvote for what? It doesn't display the items in each row!

Comment: Define `row`! In terms of a table view a *row* are all cells of a table view in the same horizontal line , in iOS it's the synonym for a cell.

Answer (score 0):

**It seems like you want to display your class properties**

**Replace the line**

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(describing: arr[indexPath.row])
```

**With**

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(arr[indexPath.row].a) \(arr[indexPath.row].b)"
```

Comment: I want to show the values in each row with respect to their titles obtained from cell.textLabel?.text
your code will just display the array in straight line.
still I will check once what you have suggested

Comment: Can you explain to me where we got the title for display?

Comment: wait , i will edit my question back and put some more info for you.

Comment: the `textLabel.text` is obtained from predefined array. And the `detailTextLabel` is obtained from the json parsed array.

Comment: Basically, we don't understand what do you want to achieve?

Comment: as the question says I just needed to display an array of a class in a table View. Please go through the answer.

Comment: So the array is a collection of similar data type, You can display the string not the array means you can display the array value, not the actual array.

Comment: exactly.. I wanted to display the array's value in subtitle. There are two arrays. One array shows title and the other array shows subtitle. The array which shows subtitle has class in it. The class has various variables in it. So it was difficult for me to print each value with respective title. So I used case to match the scenario. And the indexPath.row doesn't work here because there are two arrays.